# Search system based on two taxonomy vocabulary for Local Business Directory for Drupal 7

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, search

I am new in drupal

I am making a Local Business directory. every business entry is a node (content type "Profile") and I make two taxonomy vocabulary name as "Business-city" and "Business-category" . every node is tagged with two taxonomy term.

Now I want to make search system where user can select "Business City" and "Business category".

Please tell me how can I do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to familiarize yourself with [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module. Simply create a view of nodes of your particular content type, add two filters, one for each taxonomy, expose them and you are done.